# How to make dependent webclient calls

Tags: spring-boot, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

I need to make 3 dependent WebClient API calls. In the end, I want a Mono of FinalResponse Object.
I need to use the value from the first API response to make a call to the second API (which would return Mono of Purchase class. Purchase class would contain 2 member variables

1. user object
2. List
   Now for each value in the list, I need to make a third API call. and then return the final mono object to the controller.

I'm currently stuck with how to go about with an asynchronous call to 3rd API for each value in the list(returned by 2nd API)

service.getPurchases returns `Mono<Purchase>`. service.getSimilarItems returns `Mono<List<Item>>`.

```
class Purchase{
   private List<Item> purchasedItemsList;
}

class Item {
   private int itemId;
   private int categoryId;
   private String itemName;
}
public Mono<FinalResponse> getEndResults(UserRequest userRequest) {
        Mono<User> response1 = service.getUserResponse(userRequest);
        return response1.flatMap(response -> {
           int userId = response.getUserId();
           FinalResponse finalResponse = new FinalResponse();
           List<AllItems> itemList = new LinkedList<>();
           return service.getPurchase(userRequest, userId)
                    .map(purchasedItem -> {
                        val.getPurchasedItemsList().forEach(oneItem -> {      // please help me how to go about from here
                              service.getSimilarItemsInCategory(userRequest, userId, oneItem.getCategoryId)
                              .map(similarItem -> { 
                                AllItems allItem = new AllItems();     
                                allItem.setPurchasedItem(oneItem);
                                allItem.setSimilarItem(similarItem);
                                itemList.add(allItem);
                              });
                        });
                finalResponse.setResults(itemList);
                 return finalResponse;
                    });
        });
    }



class FinalResponse {
    private User user;
    private List<AllItems> results;
}
class AllItems {
    private Item purchasedItem;
    private List<Item> similarItem;
}
```

Basically the end response I need would look like

```
{
 "users":{//UserObject//},
 "results": [
     {
         "purchasedItem": {// Purschased Item 1},
         "similarItems": [
             {//Similar Item 1},
             {//Similar Item 2}
          ]
     },
     {
         "purchasedItem": {// Purschased Item 1},
         "similarItems": [
             {//Similar Item 1},
             {//Similar Item 2}
          ]
     }
 ]

}
```

Comment: i would suggest using functions to split up your calls so that the code becomes more readable. Write your three calls as separate functions first, then you chain them together using flatMap, and instead of using `forEach` place the list in a `Flux#fromIterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Toerktumlare's comment: This can be fairly simple, if the WebClient calls return Monos or Fluxes of simple values or lists.

You can use `flatMapMany()` or `flatMapIterable()`.

What about this simplified example?

```java
    public Mono<FinalResponse> getEndResults(UserRequest userRequest) {
        Mono<User> userResponse = service.getUserResponse(userRequest);
        return userResponse.flatMap(response -> {
                    int userId = response.getUserId();
                    return service.getPurchase(userRequest, userId)
                            .map(Purchase::getPurchasedItemsList)
                            .flatMapIterable(purchasedItems -> purchasedItems)
                            .flatMap(oneItem -> getSimilarItemInCategory(userRequest, userId, oneItem))
                            .collectList();
                })
                .map(itemList -> {
                    FinalResponse finalResponse = new FinalResponse();
                    finalResponse.setResults(itemList);
                    return finalResponse;
                });
    }

    public Mono<AllItems> getSimilarItemInCategory(UserRequest userRequest, int userId, Item oneItem) {
        return service.getSimilarItemsInCategory(userRequest, userId, oneItem.getCategoryId())
                .map(similarItem -> {
                    AllItems allItem = new AllItems();
                    allItem.setPurchasedItem(oneItem);
                    allItem.setSimilarItem(similarItem);
                    return allItem;
                });
    }
```

Comment: At the end I need to return a ```Mono<FinalResponse>``` object. and FinalResponse will have member variables as shown about in my query. So basically where do I create the object of FinalRespose? As the Purchased object in Item class value needs to be set from the response of secondAPI and ```List<SimilarItem>``` value is set from the response of thirdAPI,

@Erunafailaro Could you please help me in this.

Comment: Please add the classes of the return values of service.getPurchases() and service.getSimilarItems() to your question above. Your question can be answered best, if you provide a minimal runnable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I have done editted my code so that you could understand my requirements better and also have added how the JSON output I would need

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly. May not be 100% accurate, but should give you an idea for your own solution.

Comment: If it was helpful, I would thank you for an upvote and an accept of my answer :-)